# Android List View does not appear

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm completely new to Android Developement and this is my first day I ever touched Android studio. Just a silly question: I tried to implement Listview in MainActivity but it doesnt appear, please help.

Below is my files

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mina.mynote;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.sunny.mynote.com.example.sunny.mynote.data.NoteDataSource;
import com.example.sunny.mynote.com.example.sunny.mynote.data.NoteItem;

import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private NoteDataSource datasource;
    List<NoteItem> notesList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datasource = new NoteDataSource(this);

        refreshDisplay();
    }

    private void refreshDisplay() {
        notesList = datasource.findAll();
        ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<NoteItem>(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, notesList);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xaml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mina.mynote.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**NoteItem.Java**

```
package com.example.sunny.mynote.com.example.sunny.mynote.data;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Sunny on 19/04/2015.
 */
public class NoteItem {
    private String key;
    private String text;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public  static NoteItem getNew()
    {
        Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        String pattern;
        pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";

        SimpleDateFormat formatter;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        String key = formatter.format(new Date());

        NoteItem note = new NoteItem();
        note.setKey(key);
        note.setText("");
        return note;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getText();
    }
}
```

**NoteDataSource.Java**

```
package com.example.sunny.mynote.com.example.sunny.mynote.data;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 * Created by Sunny on 19/04/2015.
 */
public class NoteDataSource {

    private static final  String PREFKEY = "notes";
    private SharedPreferences notePrefs;

    public NoteDataSource(Context context)
    {
        notePrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFKEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    public List<NoteItem> findAll()
    {
        Map<String, ?> notesMap = notePrefs.getAll();

        SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<String>(notesMap.keySet());



        List<NoteItem> noteList = new ArrayList<NoteItem>();
        for (String key : keys)
        {
            NoteItem note = new NoteItem();
            note.setKey(key);
            note.setText((String) notesMap.get(key));
            noteList.add(note);
        }
        return noteList;
    }

    public boolean update(NoteItem note)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = notePrefs.edit();
        editor.putString(note.getKey(), note.getText());
        editor.commit();

        return true;
    }

    public boolean remove(NoteItem note)
    {
        if (notePrefs.contains(note.getKey()))
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = notePrefs.edit();
            editor.remove(note.getKey());
            editor.commit();
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have data?

Comment: i'm sure I have data in ListView,I'm expect "Updated" to appear on ListView but nothing shows up. Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your `notesList` has any data.
2. I suggest you to use `SimpleAdapter` or override the `BaseAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem is to add this code in refreshDisplay function

```
notesList = datasource.findAll();
ArrayList<String> notesListString =  new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<notesList.size();i++)
{
    notesListString.add(notesList.get(i).toString());
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notesListString);
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works :)

First of all in MainActivity in refreshDisplay:

```
ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<NoteItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notesList);
```

use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`istead of`R.layout.list_item_layout`

2. Edited NoteItem getNew()

   `note.setText(key)` instead of `note.setText("")`
3. I added

   `datasource = new NoteDataSource(this);
   datasource.update(NoteItem.getNew());`

and I run your app 4 times :) 
result: http://www81.zippyshare.com/v/DPnpaT5B/file.html
You probably run your app once with many `datasource.update(NoteItem.getNew()` and this is your problem :D
In findAll method you used `Set` which remove duplicates :)
And if you want use custom layout in ArrayAdapter take a look here [Add a Button to a ListView for each Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708159/add-a-button-to-a-listview-for-each-element/29714527#29714527) at my answer :)